# Place a table in the bottom of a printable page with css

Tags: html, css

I have an A4 page for print:

```
.page 
{
    width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
    padding: 1.2cm;
    margin: 1cm auto;
    border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Inside this page I'm trying to put in the bottom a table:

```
   <table id="t_obs">
        <tr>
            <td>TEXT</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

With the css:

```
#t_obs
{
   position: absolute;
   bottom:0px;
}
```

But only with bottom: -100px it's going to the bottom, why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `position:relative` to .page

```
  .page 
{
    width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
    padding: 1.2cm;
    margin: 1cm auto;
    border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position:relative;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RHS8X/)

Comment: You really must be desperate for an upvote after getting it wrong the first time :)

Comment: Hi, thanks. But why relative to the page, and not my table relative to the page?

Answer (score 1):

Works when you add `position:relative` to `.page`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/8EZv6/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks. But why relative to the page, and not my table relative to the page?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `position: relative` to `.page` like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/qX2Kb/

Comment: Hi, thanks. But why relative to the page, and not my table relative to the page?

Comment: So currently your are positioning your table absolute, which means it is positioned absolutely to the html page and not to your `.page` element. Giving `.page` position relative allows anything inside it to be positioned absolutely to its container rather than the html page. So in this case the container is `.page`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `position: absolute` the element you position is only positioned with regards to the closest parent with `position` specified. If you don't specify `position` for any parent it will be positioned relative the body.

If you want your table to be positioned relative the containing `.page` element ,then you should add `position: relative` to the CSS for `.page`

```
.page {
     position: relative;
     ...
}
```

Hopefully this will help show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/2nx8Z/4/

You can read more about positioning here: http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Hi, thanks. But why relative to the page, and not my table relative to the page?

Comment: I meant that the table will be positioned within the element with `.page` if you add `position: relative;` to the `.page` element. You should still have the CSS for `#t_obs` as it is now. I find this useful for positioning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Have a look at the fiddle i posted. It tries to show the difference between having position declared for the parent.